# Why is x <= x false?

Tags: python, numpy, precision

The title is a bit misleading, because it's not exactly x and x, it's x and 0.3; however, the values *should* be the same.

I have:

```
arr = np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)
```

and I receive:

```
arr[arr <= 0.3]
> array([0., 0.1, 0.2])
```

The correct result should be:

```
arr[arr <= 0.3]
> array([0., 0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
```

I have not yet stumbled upon this problem. I know it is related to floating point precision ... but what can I do here?

Comment: Well... `arr[arr.round(1) <= 0.3]` works...

Comment: So should I *always* round numbers before performing any comparisons?

Comment: Equivalence between floats is always a risky thing to test for.

Comment: @Xiphias depends on your use case - one way is to store the above as 0-10... and use plain ints as you're aware of the precision and ints don't have floating point shennigans - but that may not be practical

Comment: `np.linspace` is generally a much better option than `np.arange` for floating-point ranges - particularly, it gives you much better control of the endpoints - but it won't save you from all rounding error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't rely on comparing floats for equality (unless you know *exactly* what floats you are dealing with).
Since you know the stepsize used to generate the array is 0.1,

```
arr = np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)
```

you could increase the threshold value, 0.3, by half the stepsize to find a new threshold which is safely between values in `arr`:

```
In [48]: stepsize = 0.1; arr[arr < 0.3+(stepsize/2)]
Out[48]: array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3])
```

---

By the way, the `1.1` in `np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)` is an application of the same idea -- given the vagaries of floating-point arithmetic, we couldn't be sure that `1.0` would be included if we wrote `np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1)`, so the right endpoint was increased by the stepsize.

---

Fundamentally, the problem boils down to [floating-point arithmetic being inaccurate](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate):

```
In [17]: 0.1+0.2 == 0.3
Out[17]: False
```

So the fourth value in the array is a little bit greater than 0.3.

```
In [40]: arr = np.arange(0,1.1, 0.1)
In [41]: arr[3]
Out[41]: 0.30000000000000004
```

---

Note that rounding may not be a viable solution. For example,
if `arr` has dtype `float128`:

```
In [53]: arr = np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1, dtype='float128')

In [56]: arr[arr.round(1) <= 0.3]
Out[56]: array([ 0.0,  0.1,  0.2], dtype=float128)
```

Although making the dtype `float128` made `arr[3]` closer to the decimal 0.3,

```
In [54]: arr[3]
Out[54]: 0.30000000000000001665
```

now rounding does not produce a number less than 0.3:

```
In [55]: arr.round(1)[3]
Out[55]: 0.30000000000000000001
```

Comment: Even if you didn't know the step size, you *might* still be able to do something like `arr[arr <= 0.3 + sys.float_info.epsilon]` - however, I'm not at all confident that will *always* be enough to guarantee the comparison works... What are your thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure how to quantify just how far off the values in `np.arange(...)` may be from their idealized decimal counterparts. Depending on the floats, the gap between successive floats changes and could be greater than `sys.float_info.epsilon`. For example, 
`x = 10.3; (np.nextafter(x, np.inf) - x) > sys.float_info.epsilon`.

Comment: Yeah... I'll do my poor brain a favour and not think about it :)

Comment: Here's a case where add `sys.float_info.epsilon` is insufficient:  `x = 1.83; arr = np.arange(x,x+1.1, 0.1); arr[arr <= x+0.3+sys.float_info.epsilon]` returns `array([ 1.83,  1.93,  2.03])`.

Answer (score 1):

Unutbu points out the main problem. You should avoid comparing floating point numbers, as they have a round off error.

However this is a problem many people come across, therefore there is a function that helps you getting around this problem; `np.isclose` in your case this would lead to:

```
arr[np.logical_or(arr <= 0.3, np.isclose(0.3, arr))]
>>> array([0., 0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
```

In this case this might not be the best option, but it might be helpful to know about this function.

Sidenote:
In case nobody has ever explained to you, why this happens. Basically computer save everything in binary, however 0.1 is a periodic number in binary, this means that the computer can't save all the digits (as there are infinitely many). The equivalent in decimal would be:

1/3+1/3+1/3 = 0.33333 + 0.33333 + 0.33333 = 0.99999

Which is not 1